# How do TOR nodes select the CircID's when creating, or extending, a circuit?

Tags: networking, security, cryptography, tor

I am coding my own version of TOR and I am trying to set up circuit management. I looked at the TOR spec and it says:

> To prevent CircID collisions, when one node sends a CREATE/CREATE2
> cell to another, it chooses from only one half of the possible values
> based on the ORs' public identity keys.

I would like to implement this approach in my code as well, but I don't understand how can the node figure out what values are possible, and determine the CircID, using the OR's identity keys?

I assume there is a way to pass information using identity keys, but I couldn't find any relevant explanation, and checking the TOR-design.html also didn't help.

Comment: stackoverflow.com is for Pro Grammer the best solution

Comment: @djdomi I think so too but they keep disapproving my question and I'm tired of fighting them. This site should also be good though since my question is about networking

Comment: Im sorry about that but I think it depends on how you asked the question. if you have already been done and needs improvement then stackoverflow.com is the right way. but I would like to inform you that this site requires business related environmental question, which mostly Program a programm is not suitable. I searched a bit for you and found https://tor.stackexchange.com/ which is imho what you looking for

Comment: @djdomi Thank you very much! I've been trying to ask this for days without success.

Comment: The Question has been answered on TOR In reference https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/23675/how-do-tor-nodes-select-the-circids-when-creating-or-extending-a-circuit